# How to import new dynamic module in service?

Tags: nestjs

I have dynamic module with params. I use params in his service.
How to import this module in service another module.

If I use this, I must add all parameters and another services, which I use there.

```
const serviceDynamicModule = new ServiceDynamicModule(param, service, ...);
```

I have found `ModuleRef`, but it doesn't contain this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your module in another module by listing module you want to import to `import` section of another module's `@module` decorator.

Here is a explanation on Modules and dynamic module please check that out for more detail explanation. [Nest_docs#dynamicModule](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#dynamic-modules)

eg:-
lets say you want to import your dynamic module here.

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';

@Module(
  import:[yourDynamicModule.forRoot(neededParams)]
)
export calss MyModule{}
```